# Greatest value of digits from adding numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\begin{array}
&&N&R\\
+&R&N\\\hline
A&B&C
\end{array}$

The addition problem above is correct. If N, R, A, B, and C are different digits, what is the greatest possible value of B+C?

is there an non-pluggining in way( maybe algebraic, geometric...) to prove that the greatest possible value of B+C=11?

I don't find plugging in numbers to solve this problem a good solution as I can't think of all the possible numbers. If possible, how do you plug in numbers and quickly determine that B+C is at most 11?

Comment: Can $A$ be $0$? If so, 18 + 81 = 099, but $9 = 9 = 18$

Comment: Yes. but B and C have to be different digits, so If B=9 then C cannot be 9. You said that B and C=9.

Comment: I didn't find it hard at all to think of all possible numbers. There are only 100 possible two-digit numbers if you consider leading zeroes. Nor do I see why plugging them all in isn't a good solution. Tinkering with Excel gave me the correct answer in a matter of minutes. Personal enjoyment or pride aside, the right answer is still the right answer, no?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that there is a solution that doesn't involve any case checking, but here are some observations that will help:

- NR $= 10 N + R$ and RN $= 10R + N$ so $$\text{NR}+\text{RN}=11N +11R=11(N+R)$$
- ABC is divisible by $11$, and since $$\text{ABC}=100A + 10B + C \equiv A-B+C \pmod {11}$$we must have $A+C \equiv B \pmod{11}$, and hence since $0 \le A,C\le 9$, $$A+C=B$$
- To maximise $B+C$, we therefore wish to minimise $A$ and maximise $B$. We can check $A = 0$ is not possible, so $A \ge 1$. If $A = 1$, checking cases we see that $B=6$ and $C=5$.

Answer (score 1):

No real way to avoid cases.

Since $B\neq C$ then $R+N=10+C$, and $B=1+C$, and $B+C=1+2C$.

If $C=6$ then the only unequal solution to $R+N=16$ is $R,N=7,9$ and then $B=7$, which means $7$ repeats.

If $C=7$ then $R,N=8,9$ and then $B=8$, so $8$ repeats.

If $C>7$ then there is no pair of distinct $R,N$.

If $C=5$ then $R,N=78$ gives an example, and then $B=6$ and $B+C=11$.

Comment: why community wiki?

Comment: I sometimes do that when I consider the answer unworthy of earning me points :) @Aditya

Answer (score 0):

"NR" in decimal notation is $10 N + R$, "RN" is $10 R + N$, so the sum is $11(R+N)$.  $R+N$ is the sum of two distinct nonzero digits, which  could be
anything from $3$ to $17$, but ABC must have three digits, so $R + N > 9$.
That leaves just 8 possibilities: 
$$\eqalign{11 \times 10 &= 110\cr
         11 \times 11 &= 121\cr
         11 \times 12 &= 132\cr
         11 \times 13 &= 143\cr
         11 \times 14 &= 154\cr
         11 \times 15 &= 165\cr
         11 \times 16 &= 176\cr
         11 \times 17 &= 187\cr}$$
But $N+R=17$ only happens with $8+9$ (in either order), and the $8$ conflicts with B.  Similarly $N+R=16$ only happens with $7+9$, and the $7$ conflicts.
$N+R=15$ happens with $6+9$ or $7+8$, and the latter provides a solution with $B+C=11$: $78 + 87 = 165$.